# React Native - Screen flicker on Android with stack navigation

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, react-navigation, flicker

On Android only: every time when navigating between screens in stack navigation there will be a white flickering.
This is much harder to see on a light background but on a black screen background it is very noticeable.

I have already found the workarounds by setting setting the dark theme (or background color) on `NavigationContainer` but we using black and white backgrounds in our application so it is still visible at one of them. (and the flickering is still there but harder to see).

Also tried `animationEnabled: false` but then you have no animation at all when you navigate.

There have been previous issues but I haven't really found a good solution for this yet.

Also created an issue on the react-navigation GitHub (with example repo): [click](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10951)

[White flickering on Samsung Galaxy S20+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYFJP.gif)

Comment: Try setting backgroundColor to black in [cardStyle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#cardstyle)

Comment: where did you put the white background screen/component?

Comment: @TayyabMazhar Thanks, I already tried it but it don't changing anything.

Comment: @jted95 I tried it on `screenOptions` and then `cardStyle` `backgroundColor`.
And setting the dark theme (or background color) on NavigationContainer but we using black and white backgrounds in our application so it is still visible at least by one of them.